# Enterprice portal application in .Net other than Sharpoint

Tags: asp.net, .net, enterprise-portal

My client need an enterprise web portal app where  a set of applications will be shown in the portlets and he can work on those portlets or navigate to the particular web application by clicking the relevant portlet. I would like to know about the available software that I can use to develop the Portal in .Net since the client is a .Net company.

I know SharePoint and Microsoft Dynamics is there by I need to know other alternatives available in .net language stack .

Answer (score 0):

You can install AX addons to Visual Studio that will allow you to access AOT objects in a .net application. You can find an example in my response here:
[How to use microsoft's Dynamics AX classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130168/how-to-use-microsofts-dynamics-ax-classes/18134713#18134713)